# How to scroll multiple recyclerview (large quantity, over 1000 recyclerview) without lag?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling

I have 1000 horizontal **RecyclerView**, how to scroll all when user scroll one RecyclerView?

Thank you :D

[image]

Comment: `"I have 1000 horizontal recyclerview"` what do you have? what does `1000 horizontal recyclerview` mean?

Comment: get the first visible item of scrolled recyclerview then scroll the rest of them to that position. Simple!

Comment: Mean: i add 1000 recyclerview in an android layout, so sorry, my english not good!

Comment: You said you have already 1000 recyclerview. by the way why you are using 1000 recyclerviews. Specify your issue, may be there is a better way

Comment: so you have 1000 different `RecyclerView`s in your activity??? what for?

Comment: @IshaanKumar maybe lagging?

Comment: @pskink yes (y)

Comment: use ONE `RecyclerView` with the right `LayoutManager`

Comment: @IshaanKumar  I'm creating ganttchart for my app, ganttchart will show all tasks is loaded from server? task quantity is large, over 1000 tasks, can u have other solution? :D

Comment: @pskink I'm creating ganttchart for my app, ganttchart will show all tasks is loaded from server? task quantity is large, over 1000 tasks, can u have other solution? :D

Comment: you can have 100000 tasks if you want but it does not mean you need 100000 recyclerviews for it

Comment: @pskink you can see image above, so i dont find other solution :3 can u help me?

Comment: May be GridLayoutManager. I don't know but definitely the thing you're trying is not the best solution.

Comment: @Ishaan Kumar GridLayoutManager cant solve problem, but thank u :D